# how to download facebook profile photo to my own server with php?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, avatar

i'm using graph api to connect to facebook. now i want to get the users facebook avatar and store in my own server, so later user could change photo. I could get photo through url: http://graph.facebook.com/[userid]/picture, but how to restore it directly from facebook to my server? thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to use [copy()](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php) to copy the image to your server.

Example:

```
copy("http://facebook/picture/url","/path/on/server/img.jpg");
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at

```
fopen("http://graph.facebook.com/[userid]/picture");
```

Or if it doesn't work, try:

```
file_get_contents("http://graph.facebook.com/[userid]/picture");
```

Comment: You'll need to be sure to have [allow_url_fopen](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) enabled for that to work.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work (assuming you have an access token or you can use a user_id without a token):

```
$file = 'http://graph.facebook.com/me/picture';
$newfile = 'users_picture.jpg';

if (!copy($file, $newfile)) {
    echo "failed to copy $file";
} else {
    echo "Copied Profile Picture";
}
```